# MySQL remove space before order by clause

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a table full of "title" that I want to order by title. Problem is a lot of them have a empty space before the title. I am thinking of writting a php script to fix it all (super easy) but I was curious how could I do:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY title
```

But at the same time trimming the title so it doesnt order on the empty space. All in the same query without changing the data. God I hope I make sense.

So I am really looking for a mysql solution to this. For what its worth I use Zend_Db so a solution using that would be even better but I can manage straight MySQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the TRIM function:

```
SELECT TRIM(title) as title, field2, field3 FROM products ORDER BY TRIM(title)
```

That ought to do it!

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer myself because the exact solution to my question is:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY TRIM(title)
```

I'll still accept codykrieger's answer because he made it so I found my solution.

Here is the Zend_Db answer:

```
$products->fetchAll($products->select()->order('TRIM(title) ASC'));
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure SQL query would look like this:

> UPDATE products SET title = TRIM( title )

Comment: Thanks but as I said ideally I do not change the data just trim for the order by clause.

Comment: If that's your use case that's fine.  However, it's certainly not ideal, as you need to perform an additional operation on the table for *every single query* in order to get results in the correct order.  If your table gets large, you'll see a noticeable performance decrease.

Comment: i want to say with indexes, you should watch out for sargable issues. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html